Driver not found when using ODBC MySQL Driver for Linux
Have an issue with MySQL ODBC Driver on Ubuntu 22.04 with Tableau Server.
Attempting to connect result in error:
[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc8w.so' : file not found

But file exists:
    tableau@tableau:/tmp$ namei /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc8w.so
    f: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc8w.so
     d /
     d usr
     d lib
     d x86_64-linux-gnu
     d odbc
     - libmyodbc8w.so


Originally system was installed on AL2 with ODBC Mysql Driver 5.x.x. Ofc it needed migration. Was selected Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Driver was used initially 8.2.x.
After "help" from Tableau developers it was downgraded to 8.0.x.
Error still exists. In software looks like no deep debug for driver callout. Issue must be with it, cuz no attempt to connect is made (according to dumping).
Current config:
tableau@tableau:/tmp# cat /etc/odbc.ini 

[tableau]
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc8w.so
Description = ODBC for MySQL
SERVER = <my_server_replaced>
PORT = <my_port_replaced>
Database = <my_db_replaced>
USER = <my_user_replaced>
Password = <my_pwd_replaced>

tableau@tableau:/tmp# cat /etc/odbcinst.ini 
[MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver]
Driver=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc8w.so
SETUP=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc8S.so
UsageCount=1

[MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver]
Driver=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc8a.so
SETUP=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc8S.so
UsageCount=1

Current driver:
tableau@tableau# apt info -a mysql-connector-odbc
Package: mysql-connector-odbc
Version: 8.0.33-1ubuntu22.04
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: libs
Maintainer: Oracle MySQL Product Engineering Team <mysql-build@oss.oracle.com>
Installed-Size: 23.4 MB
Depends: dpkg-dev, mysql-community-client-plugins, debconf (>= 0.5) | debconf-2.0, libc6 (>= 2.34), libgcc-s1 (>= 3.0), libodbc2 (>= 2.3.1), libodbcinst2 (>= 2.3.1), libssl3 (>= 3.0.0~~alpha1), libstdc++6 (>= 11)
Conflicts: mysql-connector-odbc-commercial
Homepage: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/
Download-Size: unknown
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: /var/lib/dpkg/status
Description: MySQL ODBC driver
 This package allows you to connect to MySQL database servers using
 ODBC, the Open Database Connectivity abstraction layer which is
 understood by a variety of database tools that cannot talk to MySQL
 databases directly.

No issues with deps:
tableau@tableau:/tmp$ ldd -v /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc8w.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffee2b70000)
    libssl.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.3 (0x000073b38da27000)
    libcrypto.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3 (0x000073b38cc00000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x000073b38da13000)
    libodbcinst.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinst.so.2 (0x000073b38d9fe000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x000073b38c800000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x000073b38d1e0000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x000073b38c400000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000073b38dad4000)
    libltdl.so.7 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7 (0x000073b38d1d5000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x000073b38d0ee000)

    Version information:
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc8w.so:
        libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.0) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        libresolv.so.2 (GLIBC_2.9) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2
        libcrypto.so.3 (OPENSSL_3.0.0) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3
        libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4.20) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (CXXABI_1.3.8) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4.9) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (CXXABI_1.3.9) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4.29) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4.18) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4.11) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (CXXABI_1.3) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4.21) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (CXXABI_1.3.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4.15) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libssl.so.3 (OPENSSL_3.0.0) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.3
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.28) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.33) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.7) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.14) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.34) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.3:
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.14) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libcrypto.so.3 (OPENSSL_3.0.3) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3
        libcrypto.so.3 (OPENSSL_3.0.0) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3:
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.15) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.14) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.25) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.33) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.7) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.16) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.34) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2:
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.14) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.34) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinst.so.2:
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.14) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6:
        libm.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_4.2.0) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
        libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
        libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.3) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
        libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.0) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.14) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.6) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.33) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.25) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.18) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.16) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.32) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.7) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.2) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.34) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1:
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.35) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.14) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.34) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6:
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7:
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.14) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.34) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6:
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

tableau@tableau:/tmp$ isql -v tableau
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+

AppArmor:
tried to disable completely -> same results.
In logs no denies from it.
So kept "as-is".
Will greatly appreciate any hint or help!

Looks like it is Tableau server issue.
As I said I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (officially marked as supported OS on website) and there is no precompiled driver 5.x available on mysql website
As workaround I built driver 5.3.13 from source and set odbcinst.ini to this:
[MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver]
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libmyodbc5w.so
UsageCount=1

So latest server will think that this is 8.x but will use 5.x...
And yes, if config name will contain 5.x -> server will throw an error.
Weird - yes. But it is working. Devs through support ticket not commenting this behavior...

Had the same problem and used the same solution. I used the precompiled generic linux drivers for 5.3.13 (https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/get/p/10/file/mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.13-linux-glibc2.12-x86-64bit.tar.gz) and it worked on Amazon Linux 2023. I have to say I wasted a lot of time on this one, compiling multiple versions of the 8.x drivers and 9.0 drivers. Such an annoying error.
